# Subquery in WHERE clause along with other conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, where-clause

Wondering why 2 queries independently execute fine and when clubbed together takes the query into an infinite loop

```
select * from TableA 
where TableA.ColumnA NOT IN (subquery..)   --> EXECUTES FINE

select * from TableA
where TableA.ColumnA IS NULL OR TableA.ColumnA = 0  --> EXECUTES FINE
```

But above queries when clubbed together, query goes into infinite loop

```
select * from TableA 
where TableA.ColumnA NOT IN (subquery..) OR TableA.ColumnA IS NULL OR 
      TableA.ColumnA = 0
```

Any help appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop or just takes longer to run (possibly due to resources like memory)?

Comment: The combined query is retrieving more rows than the previous ones. Maybe it's a resource constraint?

Comment: Try `UNION` the two results instead . What happens ?

Comment: take a look at the expected execution plans to investigate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is one of optimization.  The solution is to separate the queries into components.  The best way to express this is:

```
select a.*
from TableA a
where a.ColumnA <> 0 and a.ColumnA NOT IN (subquery..)   -- I actually recommend `not exists`
union all
select a.*
from TableA a
where a.ColumnA IS NULL OR a.ColumnA = 0 ;
```

The condition `a.ColumnA <> 0` in the first query ensures that the two subqueries return different sets -- so you can use `union all` rather than `union`.  The use `and` should still allow this subquery to optimize the same way as the original query.  If the execution plan changes, you can express the logic differently (such as in the subquery or using `not exists`) to still get an optimal plan.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `UNION ALL`

```
select * from TableA 
where TableA.ColumnA NOT IN (subquery..)   --> EXECUTES FINE
AND TableA.ColumnA <> 0

UNION ALL

select * from TableA
where TableA.ColumnA IS NULL OR TableA.ColumnA = 0  --> EXECUTES FINE
```

Comment: could give different results due to inclusion in both queries - would be better trying UNION if TableA has a unique field